# bot executes next command without waiting for message

Tags: python, discord.py

Hello I have been trying to create a application bot for my server the bot sends you a questions then the person answers then its noted down ect but my problem is that sometimes the next question would send without waiting for the answer to the previous question. this only happens most of the time. try i might i have not been able to fix the problem. I’m pretty new to python and at the end of my wits.
my code for reference:

```
import os       
from discord.ext import commands    
from discord.utils import get 
BOT_PREFIX = ("!")
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)    
a_list = []   
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print ("------------------------------------")
    print ("Bot Name: " + client.user.name)
    print ("------------------------------------")        
submit_wait = False
a_list = []
b_list = []
c_list = []
d_list = []      
@client.command(aliases=['application'])
async def app(ctx):
    a_list = []
    b_list = []
    c_list = []
    d_list = []
    submit_wait = False    
    submit_channel = client.get_channel(806404345830047744)
    channel = await ctx.author.create_dm()
    await channel.send("starting applaction!")
    await ctx.send(ctx.author.mention + "check your dms!")
    time.sleep(2)    
    def check(m):
        return m.content is not None and m.channel == channel        
    await channel.send("Do you have any prior milli sim experiance?")
    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    a_list.append(msg.content)        
    await channel.send("What time zone are you in?")        
    msg2 = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    b_list.append(msg2.content)        
    await channel.send("If a officer ordered you to break the genva convention would you do it?")        
    msg3 = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    c_list.append(msg3.content)        
    await channel.send("Is there any particular dvision you want to be in?")    
    msg4 = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    d_list.append(msg4.content)       
    await channel.send('thank you for applying! a officer will do your application as soon as they can - respound with "submit" to submit your application')
    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    if "submit" in msg.content.lower():
      submit_wait = False
      answers = "\n".join(f'{a}. {b}' for a, b in enumerate(a_list, 1))
      answer = "\n".join(f'{a}. {b}' for a, b in enumerate(b_list, 2))
      answerr = "\n".join(f'{a}. {b}' for a, b in enumerate(c_list, 3))
      answerss = "\n".join(f'{a}. {b}' for a, b in enumerate(d_list, 4))                
      submit_msg = f'Application from {msg.author} \nThe answers are:\n{answers}'
      submit_msg2 = f'{answer}'
      submit_msg3 = f'{answerr}'
      submit_msg4 = f'{answerss}'
      await submit_channel.send(submit_msg)
      await submit_channel.send(submit_msg2)   
      await submit_channel.send(submit_msg3)
      await submit_channel.send(submit_msg4)   
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. Maybe you have wrong values or it execute different code then you expect. It is called `"print debuging"`.

Comment: don't use so many empty lines. It makes code long and unreadable - and we have to scroll it to see more code.

Comment: i will try to use the print() method and i will delete the spaces

Comment: if inside function `app()` you want to assign empty list to external `a_list` then you have to use `global a_list`. The same with external `submit_wait` and `submit_wait = False` inside `app()` - it needs `global submit_wait` to assign value to external variable. If you don't use it then it creates local variable `submit_wait`

Comment: `answer`, `answerr` and `answerss` are strings so using `submit_msg2 = f'{answer}'` (etc.) is useless because it converts string into the same string. You can use `send(answer)` instead of `send(submit_msg2)`

Comment: thank you i have done what you have suggested and it mucks up less however still does and using the print debigging it doesnt really show any new info (i could be not doing it right) sorry for the late respounse.

Comment: nvm i printed the msg string and when it does muck up it was waiting for the bot to send not the client but i have no idea how to fix this or why this is happening

Comment: use `print()` in `check()` and you may see it gets bot question as user answer. You may have to check `m.author`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested code using `print()` and I think problem is because `check()` sometimes gets bot's question and it treats it as user's answer.

You have to check `m.author` in `check()` - something like this

```
@client.command(aliases=['application'])
async def app(ctx):
    submit_channel = client.get_channel(806404345830047744)
    #print('submit_channel:', submit_channel)

    channel = await ctx.author.create_dm()
    author = ctx.author

    def check(m):
        #print('m.author:', m.author)
        #print('m.content:', m.content)
        #print('m.channel:', m.channel, m.channel == channel)
        return m.author == author and m.content and m.channel == channel
```

---

Minimal working code with other changes

```
import os
import time
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print ("------------------------------------")
    print ("Bot Name:", client.user.name)
    print ("------------------------------------")

@client.command(aliases=['application'])
async def app(ctx):
    submit_channel = client.get_channel(806404345830047744)
    print('submit_channel:', submit_channel)

    channel = await ctx.author.create_dm()
    author = ctx.author

    def check(m):
        print('m.author:', m.author)
        print('m.content:', m.content)
        print('m.channel:', m.channel, m.channel == channel)
        return m.author == author and m.content and m.channel == channel

    await channel.send("starting applaction!")
    await ctx.send(ctx.author.mention + " check your dms!")
    time.sleep(2)

    await channel.send("Do you have any prior milli sim experiance?")
    answer_a = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    answer_a = answer_a.content

    await channel.send("What time zone are you in?")
    answer_b = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    answer_b = answer_b.content

    await channel.send("If a officer ordered you to break the genva convention would you do it?")
    answer_c = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    answer_c = answer_c.content

    await channel.send("Is there any particular dvision you want to be in?")
    answer_d = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    answer_d = answer_d.content

    await channel.send('thank you for applying! a officer will do your application as soon as they can - respound with "submit" to submit your application')
    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

    if "submit" in msg.content.lower():
        submit_msg = f'''Application from {msg.author}
The answers are:
1. {answer_a}
2. {answer_b}
3. {answer_c}
4. {answer_d}'''
        await submit_channel.send(submit_msg)

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so at first glance I'm picking up a few errors

Firstly, minor issue, but using `time.sleep(2)` will pause your entire bot, so if you want to let other people to run this command at the same time you may want to change this

```py
import asyncio # instead of import time
 
await asyncio.sleep(2) # instead of time.sleep(2)
```

Also you needn't repeat so much code, this should make it work exactly how you want it to

```py
import os       
from discord.ext import commands    
from discord.utils import get
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")    

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print ("------------------------------------")
    print ("Bot Name: " + client.user.name)
    print ("------------------------------------")

submit_wait = False
questions = ["Do you have any prior milli sim experiance?",
             "What time zone are you in?",
             "If a officer ordered you to break the genva convention would you do it?",
             "Is there any particular dvision you want to be in?"]

@client.command(aliases=['application'])
async def app(ctx):
    
    submit_channel = client.get_channel(810118639234973719)
    channel = await ctx.author.create_dm()
    
    await channel.send("starting applaction!")
    await ctx.send(ctx.author.mention + "check your dms!")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    
    def check(m):
        return m.content != "" and m.channel == channel

    answers = []
    for question in questions:
        await channel.send(question)
        msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
        answers.append(msg.content)
    
    await channel.send('thank you for applying! a officer will do your application as soon as they can - respound with "submit" to submit your application')
    msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)

    if "submit" in msg.content.lower():
        submit_wait = False
        answers = [f"{no+1}. {ans}" for no, ans in enumerate(answers)]
        submit_msg = [f"Application from {msg.author}",
                      "The answers are:", *answers]
        await submit_channel.send("\n".join(submit_msg))

client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```